# What kind of CSRF attack does state parameter prevent in OAuth2-based authentication?

Tags: security, authentication, google-oauth, csrf, openid-connect

I'm working on authentication part with Google OAuth2 API.
I'm using "server" flow, not "implicit".

When implementing step 1 for obtaining `code` guidelines recommend using the `state` parameter to ensure that in the end, the service provider will receive the response that correlates to the auth request he initiated.

See https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#createxsrftoken

I understand that there is a possibility that `code` can be stolen, and `redirect_uri` guessed.

But I don't understand why this is called anti-CSRF protection?

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) CSRF attack "exploits the trust that a site has in a user's browser".
As I understand something sensitive should be kept in the browser to make CSRF attack possible. The most classic example - an authentication cookie.

But what is kept in the browser in relation to OpenID-connect code flow?
It is just two consequent redirects from service provider to identity provider and back. 
The code itself is passed on callback as a URL param.
Browser's role is passive - to be redirected two times. Nothing is stored here.

So my question is what exactly kind of CSRF attack does `state` prevent? Can anyone give a detailed example? Or is it just misusing of term "CSRF" in google guidelines?

Comment: Just a useful thought: It's not just about protecting from current exploits - it's also playing safe against future exploits that haven't been thought of yet.  I can't imagine anything truly bad myself, yet, but someone will always invent some really creative attack - given enough time experience says almost everything gets attacked somehow.  Eg: getting you to reauth somehow so they can grab your details, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When using the authorization code flow in OAuth2, the user browses to the client application, which then redirects the browser to the authorization server to be logged in and get an access token.

```
302 https://auth.server/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=....
```

After you've signed in on the authorization server, it will redirect you back to the registered redirection URI with the issued code. The client application will then exchange the code for an access token and optionally go to a URL encoded in the state parameter.

Now, an attacker could trick you into clicking a link (from an email or something) like:

```
<a href="https://auth.server/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=...."
```

This would execute the same request to the authorization server. Once you logged in and the authorization server redirects you back to the client application, the client application has no way of knowing whether the incoming `GET` request with the authorization code was caused by a 302 redirect it initiated or by you clicking that hyperlink in the malicious email.

The client application can prevent this by sticking some entropy in the state parameter of the authorization request. Since the state parameter will be included as a query parameter on the final redirect back to the client application, the client application can check if the entropy matches what it kept locally (or in a secure HTTP only cookie) and know for sure that it initiated the authorization request, since there's no way an attacker can craft a URL with entropy in the state parameter that will match something the client application keeps.

Comment: Very well explained, good example, thanks! One final part though is still missing for me - what exactly can attacker put into a malformed link to make a user do something harmful? I just don't see any room for that. The `redirect_uri` is hardcoded and exact and any attempt to play with it will cause "redirect uri mismatch". And besides, the last redirect is GET and not state-changing. If on the other hand attacker malforms optional uri in the `state` then it is paradox for me - `state` parameter gives an attack surface and at the same time prevents it

Comment: Sure, if you're site adheres to REST principles, it should not change state via a GET request. However, not all sites follow these guidelines. Also, if the site supports a redirect to a URL from the state parameter, it may be vulnerable to an open-redirect attack giving the attacker an option to load any page from an attacker controlled domain.

Comment: fyrkov: it's also about designing for security, in the future.  None of us, right now, can imagine what they could do but the bad guys are really creative.  This is just one more layer to make it harder for them to get past us.

Comment: The content that's used in the CSRF URL is derived from attacker's own OAuth session. The attacker performs a (paritual) OAuth workflow independently and intercepts the HTTP traffic. The workflow is paused right after the point where they are redirected back to the client site. This is where @MvdD says "the client application has no way of knowing whether the incoming GET request with the authorization code was caused by a 302 redirect..." - the attacker plugs their own GET request here. The end result is - the user's account is now bound to the attacker's account on the other service

Answer (score 4):

The objective of CSRF is to dupe the user into performing an action (usually a destructive write action that the user wouldn't do under normal circumstances) in a website by clicking on a link sent by the attacker. An example of such an activity could be deletion of user's own account in the website. Assuming that the user is logged into the website, the requests originating from the user's browser are trusted by the website server which has no way to find out (without the CSRF token) that the user is actually duped into making that request.

In case of Google OAuth2 (Authorization code grant type), note that the initial request to the Google auth server contains the url that the user actually wants to visit after succesful authentication. An attacker can carefully contruct that url with some malicious intent and make the user use it.

The state token check enables the server ensure that the request is indeed originated from its own website and not from any other place. If the attacker creates the url with some random state token, the server wouldn't recognise that and reject the request.

Comment: By "initial request to the Google auth server contains the url that the user wants to visit" do u mean `redirect_uri`? If so can u explain pls how is it possible to forge the uri if it is checked on Google side to be present in the list of allowed redirect uris?

Comment: @fyrkov not the redirect_uri. I meant `url%3Dhttps://oauth2-login-demo.example.com/myHome` to be specific

Comment: Ok, now I see. But this desired uri is a part of the `state` parameter which itself is optional, correct? And if we as implementors of the service provider choose to ignore the `state` then this attack won't be possible, correct?

Comment: @fyrkov couldn't understand the question. The state parameter had to be present to prevent CSRF. The parameter may or may not contain the url - depends on how you implement. Two possible implementations are mentioned in the doc - cryptographically strong random number or a hash generated with some state variables which may or may not include the uri

Answer (score 2):

If you have such doubts, best resource you must refer is the specification. For OAuth 2.0, this is [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) . There is a dedicated section in the specification which discuss about [Cross-Site Request Forgery](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.12)

> Cross-site request forgery (CSRF) is an exploit in which an attacker
> causes the user-agent of a victim end-user to follow a malicious URI
> (e.g., provided to the user-agent as a misleading link, image, or
> redirection) to a trusting server (usually established via the
> presence of a valid session cookie).

From the specification perspective, you must implement **state** handling mechanism into your application

> The client MUST implement CSRF protection for its redirection URI.
> This is typically accomplished by requiring any request sent to the
> redirection URI endpoint to include a value that binds the request to
> the user-agent's authenticated state (e.g., a hash of the session
> cookie used to authenticate the user-agent).  The client SHOULD
> utilize the "state" request parameter to deliver this value to the
> authorization server when making an authorization request.

And about a detailed explanation, directly from specifaciton

> A CSRF attack against the client's redirection URI allows an attacker
> to inject its own authorization code or access token, which can
> result in the client using an access token associated with the
> attacker's protected resources rather than the victim's

Injecting an authorisation code from attacker, then manipulating your application to behave in a manner attacker wants.